# Replacing values from one column with others mulitple times

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
      id  new_id
  0   00     11
  1   11     22
  2   22      3
  3   89    100
  4   101   102
```

I want to use this dataframe to replace old ids with new ids and for this I want to make the dataframe look like this:

```
      id  new_id
  0   00      3
  1   11      3
  2   22      3
  3   89    100
  4   101   102
```

So every time an id value is present within the new_id column, I want to replace this id value with the new id value that new id value that is not present within the id column. 
How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: sounds like a network problem.

Comment: @QuangHoang is it possible to solve solely with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Brute force

```
m = dict(zip(df.id, df.new_id))
new = df.new_id.replace(m)
while not new.equals(df.new_id):
    df['new_id'] = new
    new = df.new_id.replace(m)

df

    id  new_id
0    0       3
1   11       3
2   22       3
3   89     100
4  101     102
```

---

#### Less Brute

```
def recursed_dict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        while v in d:
            v = d[v]
        yield k, v

m = dict(recursed_dict(dict(zip(df.id, df.new_id))))

df['new_id'] = df.new_id.replace(m)

df

    id  new_id
0    0       3
1   11       3
2   22       3
3   89     100
4  101     102
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try both!